# What self-defense weapons are legal in Hong Kong?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

I'm so sorry for [What self-defense weapons are legal in Hong Kong?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/142607/35670)!!! Pls don't suspend me.

1. How can I rewrite it to make it on-topic?
2. HK is way smaller than Mainland China and India. Why are [What is a good (legal) form of self defense in China](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76385/what-is-a-good-legal-form-of-self-defense-in-china) and  [What self defense items are allowed in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/123452/13759) on topic?
3. Why did just my question get downvoted?

Comment: It was closed as too broad, not off topic.  Perhaps you could describe what plans you ahve in HKG?

Comment: 2) The community votes. If you disagree with it you can flag it with mods to reopen

Comment: 3) Someone disliked it/disagreed with it. Happens all the time, even to us old-timers on here.  Don't worry about it ;)

Comment: Finally, you're not going to get suspended for a question being put on hold, don't worry ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo Thanks Mark!!! I tried to narrow question - https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/142657/35670.

Comment: @MarkMayo I plan hike but also be travelling in areas that may be near democracy protesters, like Yuen Long. But I won't go protest.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely **not be suspended** for posting one question which gets closed. So do not panic. :)

The way the site works is quite different from conventional forums and other question/answering sites. We have rules regarding what is on-topic and what is off-topic on  Travel.SE, as well as the types of questions which are allowed on SE sites in general. Have a read on our [help centre](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/help)  to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Once you do, try to [edit your question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/142607/edit) by addressing the close reason and improving it. Like Mark suggests:

> Perhaps you could describe what plans you ahve in HKG?

Also, do not hesitate to use comments on the question to ask why the question was closed, and what you can do to improve it. You have already posted on Travel Meta which is exactly what you should have done. Good job. Also posting a comment requiring clarification for the close-votes will definitely help you understand how to improve the question.